# Can I see all the "close-as-duplicate" votes made by some gold-badge holder?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

So, there is this one gold-badge holder ... who occasionally comes and scrubs that tag, and closes questions as duplicated.

My gut feeling is that 90% of those votes are correct, but from time to time they are not. When I *notice* those by chance, I put in a re-open vote.

But as said - that happens "by chance". Unless I am mistaken: when I turn the Activity profile of that user - I don't see the close votes under "all actions". And the "review" panel only shows postings that user worked on in review queues.

Thus: is there a way to find all those questions that were closed-as-dup by some single, specific user?

Comment: No there isn't, at least not on the sites themselves. (maybe SEDE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/702161/find-questions-closed-by-a-specific-gold-hammer):

```sql
Select PostId As [Post Link], CreationDate As [CloseTime]
From PostHistory
Where UserId=##UserId## And PostHistoryTypeId=10
    And CharIndex('"BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge"', [Text])>0
Order By CloseTime Desc
```

For example for [you on SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/702161/find-questions-closed-by-a-specific-gold-hammer?UserId=1531124) it shows you closed 194 as duplicates using your gold Java hammer.

Keep in mind the data there isn't live, but updated once a week, every Sunday or Monday.